# python error: obvious condition for verifying a string does not work

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a tiny (stupid) problem in python, I am working on a client-server program in order to transfer text files, and currently I am encountering some dificulties when I try to receive the file. My problem is when I ask the user if he wants to save the file, even if he enters Y or y it does not work, here is the snippet:

```
print "Listening on input"
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        pipe = open(fifoclient,'r')
        dr, dw, de = select.select([pipe], [], [], 0)
        if dr:
            content = pipe.read()
            liste = content.split("delimiter")
            expediteur = liste[1]
            filecont = liste[2]

            print "You received a file from : " + expediteur + ". Wanna save it?"
            answer = raw_input("O/N: ")
            while answer != "O" or answer != "N" or answer != "o" or answer != "n":
                print "Please enter a correct answer:\n"
                answer = raw_input("O/N: ")
            if answer == "O" or answer == "o":
                fileoutpath = str(raw_input("please enter the complete path for where you want to save the file to: "))
                while os.path.exists(fileoutpath):
                    print "THe file already exists, chose another path:\n"
                    fileoutpath = str(raw_input("please enter the complete path for where you want to save the file to: "))
                fileout = open(fileoutpath,'w')
                fileout.write(filecont)
                fileout.close()
            else:
                a = 0
```

The problem is when it asks for O/N( Oui/Non it is in french :) ). Even if I enter "o" or "O" it still tells me to enter a correct answer.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For these sort of problems it's worth translating all of your user input/responses into lowercase (or uppercase) once you get it, and then do a simple comparison without worrying about different cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you got your condition wrong.

```
answer != "O" or answer != "N" or answer != "o" or answer != "n"
```

is always true.

it is evaluated as:

```
(answer != "O") or (answer != "N") or (answer != "o") or (answer != "n")
```

as you can see, one of the statements is always true, and because they are chained by `or`, the whole expression evaluates to `True`, no matter what you input.

Change `or` to `and`, and it will work as you intended.

Answer (score 2):

that's a boolen logic error, you should write:

```
while answer != "O" and answer != "N" and answer != "o" and answer != "n":
```

or simply:

```
while answer not in "oOnN":
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider

```
# ask question, suggest answer, convert response to lower case
answer = raw_input("Are you happy? (enter Y or N)").lower()

# allow several possible responses
if answer in ("y", "yes"):
    # do whatever for 'yes' response
```

You can also reverse the test:

```
if answer not in ("y", "yes"):
    # did not answer 'yes' (or equiv)
```

Comment: Oh my god!!!!! Thank you so much. I just realized what a for i in range(100000): stupid idiot I am :)) . You are so right! It had to be "and" not "or". Such a rookie mistake. I knew that it was something stupid, but I lost couldn't find this little silly mistake. I wasn't paying attention. Thank you again!

Comment: You're most welcome, glad to help. You can show your appreciation of the help you receive here by participating actively in StackOverflow - vote for the answer that helps you the most (click on the checkmark by the answer), and sharing what you learn by answering questions.